# Scala case class unchangeable member

Tags: class, scala, case

In Scala, I have a case class representing some data:

```
case class Foo( val start : Int, val end : Int )
```

and I often use the copy method.

However, I've now reached the point where I'd like to add an extra member as an identifier, because I want the following equality behaviour:

```
case class NewFoo( val id : Int, val start : Int, val end : Int )
{
    override def equals( any : Any ) = any match
    {
        case other : NewFoo => id == other.id
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

However, I'd now like to prevent the user changing the `id` when they copy a `NewFoo` instance, thus, once a `NewFoo` is created, its data can change, but its `id` will always remain the same.

Is this possible with case classes? I suspect not, since it's not really what they're designed for. On the other hand, a definition I've read of case classes is that they are "plain and immutable data-holding objects that should exclusively depend on their constructor arguments", a definition which doesn't seem to be broken by my use case.

If a case class is inappropriate, is there a way I can replicate the functionality of a one, particularly the copy method, without having an explicit case class? I'm not using pattern matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could implement `copy` method manually like this:

```
sealed class NewFoo(val id: Int, val start: Int, val end: Int) {
  def copy(start: Int = start, end: Int = end) = new NewFoo(id, start, end)

  override def equals(any: Any) = any match {
    case other : NewFoo => id == other.id
    case _ => false
  }

  // don't forget to override `hashCode` with `equals`
  override def hashCode() = id.hashCode()
}
```

Note that you should also override `hashCode` with `equals`.

You could also make your class `sealed` to avoid problems with this `equals` implementation.

See also [Programming in Scala/Object Equality](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html).

You could also save pattern matching and instance creation without `new` (`NewFoo(0, 0, 0)`) with this companion object implementation:

```
object NewFoo {
  def apply(id: Int, start: Int, end: Int) = new NewFoo(id, start, end)
  def unapply(f: NewFoo): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Some((f.id, f.start, f.end))
}
```

Comment: I think you could have keep NewFoo as `case class` as in original, saving pattern matching capability.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on hashCode, I just left it out as it wasn't really part of the question. As for your copy implementation, that's perfect! I'd always thought of copy as some "magic method", but of course, it's just a method with each member as a parameter and the existing values as defaults. Thanks very much!

Comment: @dmitry: see update, I don't think one should use `case class` only for generated `apply` and `unapply` methods.

Comment: @paulmdavies: There is no `magic methods` in `case class`. See update - you could even use pattern matching without `case class`.

Comment: @senia - Not use case class for generated apply. Why not?

Comment: @dmitry: I guess `case class` is for "data holders" without additional logic, so other developers could expect equality based on all fields. I would be confused by `case class` with custom equality. And `apply` method is not something difficult to implement.